# How to reuse react-native StyleSheet (styles) in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

```
// react-native example
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = {
  container: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  }
}

const stylesRN = StyleSheet.create(styles);

<View style={stylesRN.container}></View>
```

What the best way to reuse

```
// inner styles 
{
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
}
```

in both react-native and react?

**What i want to achieve in pseudocode (or another way of reuse in React):**

```
<div style={magicAdapter(styles.container)}>Hello World!</div>
```

**Problem**: It is impossible to reuse all react-native inline-styles in react `as is` without magicAdapter.

Comment: do you mean you want to reuse this styles object?

Comment: Thanks for comment, question was edited

Comment: thanks. asnwered your query, have alook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is store all your styles in an object in some file `e.g. const containerStyles = { borderRadius: 2 }`, export it, then for React Native use the StyleSheets javascript class to create the styles for your div container

```js
import {containerStyles} from '../someFile.js'

const styles = StyleSheets.create({
  container: containerStyles
})
```

then for React you could do inline styling with the same object, but be aware that not all styles supported in StyleSheets can be used for inline styling, so if you want to do something equivalent there's libraries out there like `emotion.js` to dynamically load CSS in JS

https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion
Heres an example

```js
import {css} from 'emotion'
import {containerStyle} from '../someFile'

const getContainerStyles = css`
  border-radius: ${containerStyle.borderRadius}
`

export default class SomeClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div
        style={getContainerStyles}
      >
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Problem a little bit deeper: by default it impossible use react-native `StyleSheet` in React.

Comment: I updated my answer since I understood the question a little better. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, i really aware about possibility of using **all styles** from RN in react, i think the question was about that, need to edit it one more time.

Comment: For now i can't understand how to reuse styles with `emotion.js`, could you please add some example?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example use of emotion.js

Comment: Thank you, already upvote your answer but seems using `emotion` will come with a lot of boilerplate: i need to repeat all style props. Looking for a little bit clear way.

Comment: @Buggy I think this answer is the best that you'll get for what you're asking. Generally people don't share styles between react web apps and react native apps for good reason. There are a lot of features in web css that are not supported in react native (media queries, transitions etc, display: inline etc) that if you tried to use them inside a StyleSheet they would throw errors. There are also plenty of others that don't work on RN in the same way as on the web. You probably can reuse some Text styles, but in my opinion it doesn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the style of your new component with the style of container, like below

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  newComponent:{
     // New component style
  }
});

<View style={[styles.container, styles.newComponent]}> 
</View>
```

Comment: How the `styles` will be reused in react? How to use it in react-native - is clear

Comment: Added more explanation to the question

Comment: Do you mean how to use the styles in other file?

Comment: We have  two separated projects: a react and react-native. Different project, directory, builds and so on. Question: how to use the same `style` in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
// your component file name  (button.js) 
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import the style from another file present in the same directory
import styles from 'button.style.js'; 
 // you can reuse this style in another component also

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Press Me! </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Button;

// your style file  name ( "button.style.js")

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#43a1c9',
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```